# statement error for GROUP BY for whole columns

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to see everything columns in the database (by select `*`) with new columns `as`, in order that I can analyze those columns without needing copy and paste in Excel spreadsheet.

How to type at `group by` without need typing each column (that more than 10 columns), usually it comes up error if I am using this query:

```
select   a. *  
min(order_date) over(partition by customer_id) as min_order , 
max(order_date) over(partition by customer_id) as max_order , 
max(create_date) over(partition by customer_id) as max_create , 
sum (count(*)) over (partition by customer_id,
create_date order by create_date desc ) count 
from purchase a
group by a.customer_id
```

Statement error shows this:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function ORA-02063: preceding line
from OMSRPT_OMS_OBJECTS
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

***Analytic vs Aggregate Functions***

- analytic and aggregate functions are not the  same
- some aggregate functions have analytic versions and some don't
- both are dealing with the group of rows, but aggregate function returns 1 row per group always - with analytic function,
  the result    set is not automatically collapsed
- if you use analytic functions you don't need GROUP BY clause (in most cases) couse you already grouped rows using Partition By
- if you use aggregate functions with some (1 or more) non aggregated selections - you have to use Group By - by every non  aggregated selection
- combining analytic and aggregate function in one selection (like you did) - ends with error

Let's say that your sample data looks like this:

```sql
WITH
    purchase AS
        (
            Select 1 "CUSTOMER_ID", To_Date('01.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "CREATE_DATE", To_Date('01.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 'AAA' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "CUSTOMER_ID", To_Date('02.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "CREATE_DATE", To_Date('05.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 'BBB' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "CUSTOMER_ID", To_Date('04.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "CREATE_DATE", To_Date('10.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 'CCC' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "CUSTOMER_ID", To_Date('09.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "CREATE_DATE", To_Date('12.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 'DDD' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "CUSTOMER_ID", To_Date('09.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "CREATE_DATE", To_Date('14.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 'EEE' "SOME_COLUMN" From Dual 
        )
```

If you replace the last selection with analytic version and exclude the Group By clause from the code - everything works fine (corrected the code just a bit)

```sql
Select   
    a.*,  
    Min(ORDER_DATE)  OVER(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID) as min_order, 
    Max(ORDER_DATE)  OVER(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID) as max_order, 
    Max(CREATE_DATE) OVER(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID) as max_create, 
    -- the line below is excluded for using combination of SUM() OVER() analytic function with COUNT() aggregate function - you could use Count() OVER() analytic version (2 lines below)
    --  Sum(count(*))    OVER(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID, CREATE_DATE order by CREATE_DATE desc ) as sum_count 
    Count(*)     OVER(Partition By CUSTOMER_ID, CREATE_DATE order by CREATE_DATE desc ) as a_count  
From purchase a
--Group By a.CUSTOMER_ID        -- in this case you don't need GROUP BY clause
```

... having all analytic functions along with all columns from a table without GROUP BY clause results as:

| CUSTOMER_ID | CREATE_DATE | ORDER_DATE | SOME_COLUMN | MIN_ORDER | MAX_ORDER | MAX_CREATE | A_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-DEC-22 | 01-DEC-22 | AAA | 01-DEC-22 | 01-DEC-22 | 01-DEC-22 | 1 |
| 2 | 02-DEC-22 | 05-DEC-22 | BBB | 05-DEC-22 | 10-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 | 1 |
| 2 | 04-DEC-22 | 10-DEC-22 | CCC | 05-DEC-22 | 10-DEC-22 | 04-DEC-22 | 1 |
| 3 | 09-DEC-22 | 12-DEC-22 | DDD | 12-DEC-22 | 14-DEC-22 | 09-DEC-22 | 2 |
| 3 | 09-DEC-22 | 14-DEC-22 | EEE | 12-DEC-22 | 14-DEC-22 | 09-DEC-22 | 2 |